# ¿Cómo obtener el ID de un usuario al logearse en una API hecha con Laravel Passport?

Tags: laravel

Hago la petición a postman de login y me devuelve:

```
{
    "access_token": "Mi Token",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_at": "2021-08-15 21:03:21"
}
```

Pero necesito obtener el ID del usuario logeado para registrarlo junto a un formulario y guardarlo en la BD junto a la demás información.

Mis rutas API

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;


Route::group([
'prefix' => 'auth'
], function () {
Route::post('login', 'AuthController@login');
Route::post('signup', 'AuthController@signUp');
Route::post('visit', 'VisitController@store');

Route::group([
  'middleware' => 'auth:api'
], function() {
    Route::get('logout', 'AuthController@logout');
    Route::get('user', 'AuthController@user');
});
});
```

Comment: Gracias, ya actualicé la pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Justo como utilizas el facade `Auth` en web, para api tambien puedes usar

```
$user = Auth::user();
$user = request()->user();

//Si usas una instancia de Request $request
$user = $request ->user();
```